# set variables to global scope within a loop

Tags: php, loops, global-variables

I want to define a number of temporary global variables in PHP called `$MyGlobalVar1`, `$MyGlobalVar2` ... , but the problem is that the keyword 'global' takes the variable name literally:

```
for ($i = 1; $i<= 10; $i++) { 
    $var = '$MyGlobalVar'.$i;
    global $var;
}
```

i.e. `$var` is now global.

Setting quotes will not work because 'global' expects '$' and will stop execution at the single quote:

```
for ($i = 1; $i<= 10; $i++) { 
    $var = '$MyGlobalVar'.$i;
    global '$var';
}
```

How to set the variables to global scope? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you using `'` it will always be taken as string

Try
[$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) for your purpose

```
for ($i = 1; $i<= 10; $i++)
 { 
// acess as $GlOBALS['MyGlobalVar'.$i] and do whatever you want
   $GLOBALS['MyGlobalVar'.$i] = null
}
```

Comment: I think $GLOBALS still needs me to define each variable individually before being able to use them within a loop. I have no gain by using a loop then. I want to create variables and define them as global by using a loop. This will just use them if I understand you correctly.

Comment: see my edited answer.. by this method .. you are actually defining the variable to be global

Comment: Yes, dreamCoder, it works and a dump of $GLOBALS will show $MyGlobalVar1 .. 10 alright. Thanks. One more thing came up, though: When defining the globals individually they get the value &NULL, so I tried $GlOBALS['MyGlobalVar'.$i] = &null, but I get "syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM" as error message. How to set the values of my newly born vars to &NULL?

Comment: I think u want to initialize new variable to `null` just put ` $GlOBALS['MyGlobalVar'.$i] = null` instead of using `&null`.. U can set pointer to variable but not to null..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following as well:

```
for ($i = 1; $i<= 10; $i++) { 
    $varName = 'MyGlobalVar'.$i;
    global $$varName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because single quotes can't parse variables you have to use double quotes. You should know the basic difference between them.

First of all you do not need quotes around the global variable try this

```
global $var;
```

Comment: Double quotes have the same effect, i.e. 'global' expects '$' and will not tolerate single or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly try variabling your variable ie:

```
for ($i = 1; $i<= 10; $i++) { 
    $var = '$MyGlobalVar'.$i;
    $foo = $var;
    global $foo;
}
```

Comment: This is not working. Additionally, I tried global $$var; Result of your code is a global variable $foo with value $MyGlobalVar10.

Comment: remove the ' ' from $MyGlobalVar

Comment: But this string as fixed part of the variable name is a requirement.