# PHP - How to Get Value One By One?

Tags: php, api

I am doing a project using embed.ly API.

```
//Some Codes............   
$objs = $pro->oembed('https://wordpress.org/');
print_r($objs);
```

The output of above code is

```
stdClass Object ( [provider_url] => https://wordpress.org [description] => Version 4.4 of WordPress, named "Clifford" in honor of jazz trumpeter Clifford Brown, is available for download or update in your WordPress dashboard. New features in 4.4 make your site more connected and responsive. Clifford also introduces a new default theme, Twenty Sixteen. Introducing Twenty Sixteen Our newest default theme, Twenty Sixteen, is a modern take [...] [title] => WordPress › Blog Tool, Publishing Platform, and CMS [url] => https://wordpress.org/ [thumbnail_width] => 264 [thumbnail_url] => https://wpdotorg.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/gray-tshirt-swag.jpg [version] => 1.0 [provider_name] => Wordpress [type] => link [thumbnail_height] => 354 )
```

How I get values for different variable?

Example:

```
$provider_url = 'https://wordpress.org';
$descripition = 'Version 4.4 of WordPress, named "Clifford" in honor of jazz trumpeter Clifford Brown, is available for download or update in your WordPress dashboard. New features in 4.4 make your site more connected and responsive. Clifford also introduces a new default theme, Twenty Sixteen. Introducing Twenty Sixteen Our newest default theme, Twenty Sixteen, is a modern take'
```

I need to get all values separately for different variables? How I do it?

Comment: they already are in seprate variables

Comment: @Dagon How I get them to different variables? For a example if I need to display  only description, how I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would simply cast it as following:

```
$objs = $pro->oembed('https://wordpress.org/');
$objs_array =  (array) $objs;
```

and then:

```
foreach ($objs_array as $key=>$val){
   ${$key} = $val;
}
echo $provider_url;
echo $descripition;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the property like that and you know what it's going to give you you could do this:

```
$objs = $pro->oembed('https://wordpress.org');
$provider_url = $objs->provider_url
```

If you want *dynamically allocate* variables according to what the object returns you could do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515069/set-variables-to-global-scope-within-a-loop)

```
$objs = $pro->oembed('https://wordpress.org');
$a_objs = (array) $objs; // cast to array creating key => value pairs for foreach(...)
foreach ($a_objs as $key => $value) {
    $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
}
```

This would automatically create the variables for you that are keys in the object like `$provider_url`, `$title` - do note that if you don't use all of them this method is *not safe* to use due to the fact that it could potentially overwrite other global variables that you might be using for a different reason. (`$title` here being a good example of that.)